# Using exec to run PowerShell script hangs if I try to set credentials

Tags: php, powershell

Firstly I apologise but I am pretty new to PHP and PowerShell, we all have to start somewhere!  I am creating a utility where everyday IT tasks can be performed from a central web based console.  I have managed to query and report on things like password expiry by executing PowerShell scripts but have got stuck on unlocking accounts.  I query AD and return a list of locked users with a button next to each user to unlock them.  This button posts to a php page which runs another powershell script to unlock the user.
php page is:

```
    <?php    

    // Get the variables submitted by POST in order to pass them to the PowerShell script:
    $lockeduser = $_POST["unlock"];

    // Path to the PowerShell script.
    $psScriptPath = "C:\\code\\psphp\\ps\\unlock.ps1 $lockeduser 2>&1";

    // Execute the PowerShell script:
    exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath",$out,$ret);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($out);
    print_r ($ret);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

As you can see I'm trying to capture any output but at the moment the page is just hanging.

PowerShell script is:

```
param([string]$lockeduser)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$adminacc = "*myadminaccount*"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\password1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($adminacc, $encrypted)
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $lockeduser -Credential $credential
```

If I echo the command before passing it to PS it looks fine and can be executed directly from PS.

**Edit:** This is something to do with exec (or shell_exec) causing an issue when the PS script is setting credentials.  If I remove that part of the script i.e.

```
param([string]$lockeduser)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $lockeduser
```

it runs and returns that the script failed due to

> Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

Has anyone come across this before, I have searched for anything on this to no avail.  Thanks!

**Further edit**
After a bit more testing it is this PS code that doesn't work

```
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\password1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

If I change the method to

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "My Password" -AsPlainText -Force
```

it works with no problems.  Plain text passwords in files are obviously not something I want to use.  Can someone test and see if they get the same result?

Comment: You have multiple versions of Powershell on you computer. See [this](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/) article. Maybe that could explain your "incorrect format" error.

Comment: @JeroenHeier You cannot have multiple versions of PS on a PC unless you're referring to the emulated V2, or PowerShell Core which is a different product and executable.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I can run other scripts in the same way so I don't think it is multiple versions.  I think this may be to do with permissions in a way.  I can manually run the ps script and it works fine (uses programmed credentials) but when I try to execute the script using exec or shell_exec it hangs.  If I remove the setting of admin credentials in the ps script it runs (but fails due to insufficient permissions).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it was all just me being a newb.  Executing the script via the php page must not be running it as my account.  My account was the one that set the credentials and stored it in the file so is the only one that can decrypt it.  I have changed the convertto-securestring method to use keys instead of default and it now works.